# Unable to load Sass / Compass after installing RVM, to use with Assetic in Symfony2

Tags: php, ruby, symfony, rvm, assetic

I was trying to use Capifony, which requires Capistrano, which requires Ruby. But my apt version of ruby was old and was throwing syntax errors. So then I installed RVM and did this:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
$ rvm --rvmrc --create use 1.9.3@myapp
$ gem install sass [--pre]
$ gem install compass [--pre]
$ updatedb
$ locate sass | grep myapp | grep bin
$ locate compass | grep myapp | grep bin
```

Copied and pasted those paths to config.yml

```
    sass:
        bin: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.277/bin/sass
        #apply_to: "\.scss$"
    compass:
        bin: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/bin/compass
        apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

Everything about Compass and Sass worked fine before switching to RVM.
Compass/Sass still seem to work from app_dev.php, but they break when I try to dump assets for production:

```
$ rm -r app/cache/ # this is how I delete cache, any other way give me errors, even before having this compass problem. This have always worked fine. I removed the * because this code block was interpreting it as a comment
$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
Dumping all prod assets.
Debug mode is off.

00:05:36 [file+] /home/www/dev/public/myapp/app/../web/css/fcd6640.css



  [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                                                  
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                                                     
  '/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby' '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/bin/compass' 'compile' '/t  
  mp' '--config' '/tmp/assetic_compassF1Mv7t' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compassKDoaEA.scss'                                         

  Error Output:                                                                                                                                        
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError  
  )                                                                                                                                                    
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'                                      
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/lib/compass/dependencies.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'           
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/lib/compass/dependencies.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'                     
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'                                      
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'                                      
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'                         
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'                                              
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'                                  
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'                                      
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'                                      
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/bin/compass:20:in `block in <main>'                                     
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'                                   
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.13.alpha.0/bin/compass:19:in `<main>'                                              


  Output:                                                                                                                                              
  Unable to load Sass. Please install it with one of the following commands:                                                                           
    gem install sass --pre                                                                                                                             


  Input:                                                                                                                                               
  $main-color: red;                                                                                                                                    

  body {                                                                                                                                               
    color: $main-color;                                                                                                                                 
  }
```

Another error I have been getting:

```
Error Output:                                                                                                                                        
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find compass (>= 0) amongst [big decimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
```

Related: @mpapis @jamz [Sass broken after install with RVM, using Assetic PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979956/sass-broken-after-install-with-rvm-using-assetic-php)

I would like to add more tags: compass and sass. Not sure if can be done with higher score.

**UPDATE**

I added a wrapper like this:

```
$ rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp php sass compass
```

And edited config.yml again, but now I get these errors alternated, randomly:

Error 1:

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                                                  
  An error occurred while running: '/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby' '/usr/local/rvm/bin/php_compass' 'compile' '/tmp' '--config' '/tmp/assetic_compass0Tmn8t' '--sass- dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compasssw2S3k.scss'                                                                                             

  Error Output: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)                                              
Input:                                                                                                                                               
  $main-color: red;                                                                                                                                    

  body     {                                                                                                                                               
    color: $main-color;                                                                                                                                 
  }
```

Error 2:

```
Error Output: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:22:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)                                                                                                                                
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:213:in `default_gemfile'
```

Compass still works fine through app_dev.php

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Solution**

Just use [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/). It can be installed with Composer, and then in config.yml:

```
    lessphp:
         php: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
         apply_to: "\.less"
```

Comment: @alex88 I tried, I really did. And I had used ruby and rails in the past. Enough with the ruby nonsense, php + less for the win.

Comment: oh sure :) me too, it can be a PITA some times.. one nice missing thing is sprite generation :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need a wrapper:

```
rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp php sass compass
```

this will generate wrappers which will call proper ruby(rvm) environment, use them like:

```
sass:
    bin: /usr/local/rvm/bin/php_sass
    #apply_to: "\.scss$"
compass:
    bin: /usr/local/rvm/bin/php_compass
    apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it threw a different error, I updated my post

Comment: This is totally random, now it says 'Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)'. Looks like a compass bug, since I'm not using Bundler.

Comment: for the second error try `gem uninstall rubygems-bundler` - there was a bug in `compass` that when connected with `rubygems-bundler` could generate this error