# Why is no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)?

Tags: ruby, sass, rbenv

Ruby is installed by rbenv.

```
$ ruby -v  
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [i686-linux]

$ which ruby  
/home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby

$ which sass  
/home/user/.rbenv/shims/sass

$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0) 
bundler (1.2.4)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
sass (3.2.5)
```

This is my config.yml:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    // ...

    ruby: /home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
            bin: /home/user/.rbenv/shims/sass

        // ...
```

This is the error I get:

```
[message] An error occurred while running:
'/home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby' '/home/user/.rbenv/shims/sass' '--load-path' '/path/to/symfony2/src/My/AnyBundle/Resources/public/css' '--cache-location' '/tmp' '/tmp/assetic_sassYbl6MI'

Error Output:
ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

The error in my other setup:

config.yml:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    // ...

    ruby: /home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass: ~

        // ...
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error Output:
ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/sass (LoadError)
```

Sass does not function.  Is it a problem referencing the gem?

Comment: This article helped me resolving this issue: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/compass-loaderror-in-assetic-and-symfony2/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+symfony%2Fplanet+%28Symfony+Blog+Planet%29&utm_medium=feed

Answer (score 9):

I've got this error after cloning a rails repo:

```
$ rails server
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

The problem was in `bin/rails` and `bin/rake`. Top line was `#!/usr/bin/env`, but should have been `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.

Comment: I missed these line completely and had to add them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Sf 2.1.7, rvm installed, installed compass,sass as gem, particulary based on [Unable to load Sass / Compass after installing RVM, to use with Assetic in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752142/unable-to-load-sass-compass-after-installing-rvm-to-use-with-assetic-in-symfo)

```
parameters:
# Assetic
  assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images
  assetic.filter.compass.http_path:  /images
  assetic.ruby.bin: 'pathToRubyBin'
```

path to ruby bin you can check by:

```
which ruby
```

as above.
For sass and scss use compass filter:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ FOSUserBundle, XcomplSomeBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        sass: ~
        compass:
            bin: 'pathtocompass'
            apply_to: "~\.(sass|scss)$~"
        cssrewrite: ~
```

And here is Warning! There is no need 100500 wrappers to create if you use rvm or system ruby.
Just:

```
$ which compass
```

And it is your pathtocompass.

And now:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'css/general.scss(or .sass)' filter='compass, cssrewrite' output='css/general.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href={{ asset_url }} />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, my gemlist:

```
~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.2.4)
chunky_png (1.2.7)
compass (0.12.2)
fssm (0.2.10)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sass (3.2.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in Rubymine. This was due to the Auto-detection of bundler being enabled.

Disabling Auto-detection of bundler solved my issue.
You can disable bundler like this -

`Run->Edit Configurations->Bundler tab in the respective configuration -> Choose Disabled`