# Install HomeBrew and ruby LoadError question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I was install HomeBrew，bec my area and network problem, terminal tells me:

```sh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused
```

So, I just install HomeBrew was used by install.rb file and ruby command, but the ruby was callback:

```rb
Traceback (most recent call last):

ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

Thanks.

Reference：

[Homebrew installation on Mac OS X Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910217/homebrew-installation-on-mac-os-x-failed-to-connect-to-raw-githubusercontent-com)

[Why is no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887335/why-is-no-ruby-script-found-in-input-loaderror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install homebrew using all the steps from this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/.
Also im not sure what you mean by the install.rb, what are you trying to do?