# 500 error when compiling scss in symfony2

Tags: symfony, assetic

I am getting a 500 error when compiling scss files with assetic. Strangely enough, using `php app/console assetic:dump` the scss compiles without issue. Resources in `web/bundles` are relative symlinks.

I'm running OSX 10.8, symfony 2.3, and php 5.4.20.

**config.yml**

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
          apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

**base.html.twig**

```
{# ... #}
{% stylesheets
    filter='cssrewrite'
    'bundles/acmehello/css/main.css'
    'bundles/acmehello/scss/page.scss'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
{# ... #}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the fact that I am using [rvm](http://rvm.io/), which causes issues with sass paths (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752142/unable-to-load-sass-compass-after-installing-rvm-to-use-with-assetic-in-symfo) SO answer).

To solve this, I generated an rvm [gemset](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) with:

```
# will create 'php_sass' and 'php_compass' executables in $GEM_HOME
rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p194 php sass compass
```

And added the following to my config.yml file:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: true
    bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scss:
          sass: /Users/Nick/.rvm/bin/php_sass
          apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

SCSS files now compile just fine. Compass users will need to point assetic to the gemset for compass