# Assetic SASS compile error

Tags: symfony, sass, assetic, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to get a Symfony 2 project running on the Cloud9 IDE/VM. I've installed all the required libraries but for some reason Assetic is not able to compile the SASS files.

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                                                 
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                                                    
  '/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby' '/mnt/shared/sbin/sass' '--load-path' '/home/ubuntu/workspace/lossless-webapp/app/../web/css' '--scss'  
   '--cache-location' '/tmp' '/tmp/assetic_sassoc5zv2'                                                                                                
  Error Output:                                                                                                                                       
  /mnt/shared/sbin/sass:1: unknown regexp options - hard                                                                                              
  /mnt/shared/sbin/sass:1: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot                                                                     
  ..._PATH=/mnt/shared/lib/ruby/1.9.1 /nix/store/yrs58pvf72cn1mca...                                                                                  
  ...                               ^                                                                                                                 
  /mnt/shared/sbin/sass:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('                                                                           
  ...PATH=/mnt/shared/lib/ruby/1.9.1 /nix/store/yrs58pvf72cn1mcax...                                                                                  
  ...                               ^                                                                                                                 
  /mnt/shared/sbin/sass:1: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot                                                                     
  ...n1mcax0s685yw2dqzzvqv-ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/sass "$@"                                                                                              
  ...                               ^                                                                                                                 
  /mnt/shared/sbin/sass:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('                                                                           
  ...1mcax0s685yw2dqzzvqv-ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/sass "$@"                                                                                               
  ...                               ^                                                                                                                 
  /mnt/shared/sbin/sass:1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('                                                   
  ...zvqv-ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/sass "$@"                                                                                                               
  ...                               ^                                                                                                                 
  Input:
  ...
```

From what I figure it is a problem with the SASS call by Assetic, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

We just updated our documentation on using Symfony on our documentation site (thanks to Timo Haberkern): https://docs.c9.io/frameworks_symfony2.html

Does this article help? If not, where do you get stuck, including steps, error messages etc.?

Comment: Symfony 2 itself is working just fine, only SASS via assetic dose not seem to compile. I'm not sure if this is a problem in the Cloud9 VM, Ruby, SASS or Assetic ...

Comment: Is the Cloud9 vm using RVM (Ruby Version Manager)? That could be causing the problem, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19416750/461992

Comment: Yes, Cloud9 is using RVM so I suggest to test the solution provided in the link by wowpatrick.